# Replace first and second occurrence with different characters

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a vba code that does bulk replace.

I'd like to (etheir trough VBA or formula) replace first occurence of "%" with "(" and second occurence of "%" with ")" for each cell.

i have my data in column B.

This is my VBA code :

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("_", "VOSTFR.mp4", "VF.mp4")
rplcList = Array(" ", "VOSTFR", "VF")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

  Next x

End Sub
```

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter either of the following formula in `Cell C1`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"%","(",1),"%",")",1)
```

or

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(B1,FIND("%",B1),1,"("),FIND("%",REPLACE(B1,FIND("%",B1),1,"(")),1,")")
```

Drag/Copy as required. See image for reference.

[image]

If there are less then two `%`, formula will throw error. So to avoid error use `IFERROR` in formula as

```
=IFERROR(REPLACE(REPLACE(B1,FIND("%",B1),1,"("),FIND("%",REPLACE(B1,FIND("%",B1),1,"(")),1,")"),"")
```

Comment: another thing also is i'd like to be able change multiple characters with a single formula ( like replace "/" with "\"  & replace "@" with "#"). I'm new to excel and your formula got be a bit confused because it calls "%" 3 times only to change it 2 times. so i don't know how to customize it. thanks a lot !

Comment: @Mk1 - Use `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"@","#"),"/","\")`

Comment: Thanks so much ! i dont have enough reputaion to upvote you but it says its taken into consideration  when i do

Comment: @Mk1 - I've added another formula in the answer.